# Prestashop add class to all Subcategories

Tags: class, prestashop, smarty

I try to add a div class to a category and this need to be work for all subcategories.

Example

```
<div class="{if category->id == '1' || $category->id_parent == '1'}newformat{/if}"</div>
```

But this just add the class for the category self and the first subcategories, not the sub-subcategories and the levels below.

How can add the class for all level depth inside the category 1?

Comment: Your question need more details

Comment: I have a container like <div class="container">code here </div>

Comment: and i have my categories inside a megamenu. I have Level 1 categories , level 2 and level 3.

Comment: What i need: i need a additional class in the container foreach level 1 categories and all child categories or subcategories.

Comment: Here example : CAT1 , SUBCAT1 , SUB-SUBCAT1 need a class: frame1, CAT2, SUBCAT2, SUB-SUBCAT2 need a class frame2----> then looks like <div class="container frame2">code here </div>

Answer (score 0):

Ist that maybe possible with getAllChildren?

Comment: Depending on the structure of your TPL file (Share it). You can do this by Smarty or jQuery

Comment: do you have skype? can i contact you about this? my account is a.majzer

Comment: {if $page_name !='index' && $page_name !='pagenotfound'}{if isset($warehouse_vars.breadcrumb_width) && $warehouse_vars.breadcrumb_width == 0}{include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"}{/if}{/if}
  <div class="columns-container">

Comment: is just about <div class="columns-container">

Comment: is the header.tpl

Comment: PS.1.6.1.20 Version